# Getting no result

Tags: python, python-3.x

So, I'm getting `suma = 0` (I have to get 3841, by summing numbers from a file), after I have added string `kiekis` (for getting number of lines in a file) and when I removed `kiekis` for test, I saw that `suma` actually not changed.

```
ugis = open("duomenys.txt")

kiekis = len(ugis.readlines())

sum(int(s) for s in ugis)
suma = 0
for s in ugis: suma += int(s)

print(suma, kiekis) #Its for check numbers

vidurkis = suma/kiekis

print("Vidurkis:", vidurkis)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you called `readlines()`, you've exhausted the file iterator - the `for s in ugis` loop later would make 0 iterations.

Instead you can read the contents into a list and then get the average:

```
with open("duomenys.txt") as f:
    data = [int(line.rstrip()) for line in f]

vidurkis = sum(data)/len(data)
print("Vidurkis:", vidurkis)
```